# TypeScript Functions compilation error while deploying to firebase

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I am using typescript functions to upload to my firebase cloud. The functions are working fine for my friend but when i try to compile and deploy the functions to firebase I recieve the following error.

```
D:\func\functions>firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'educapp-4362a'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint D:\func\functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json


ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:13:22 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:16:22 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:17:22 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:21:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:21:9 - Identifier 'inJsonFormat' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:21:54 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:27:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:27:9 - Identifier 'batch' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:31:49 - != should be !==
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:33:21 - != should be !==
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:35:13 - Identifier 'connectionsArray' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:43:13 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:43:17 - Identifier 'connectionProfileRef' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:46:13 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:46:17 - Identifier 'parentMap' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:56:13 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:56:17 - Identifier 'ref1' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:61:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:61:9 - Identifier 'ref2' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:77:22 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:80:23 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:83:26 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:84:26 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:103:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:103:9 - Identifier 'map' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:105:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:105:9 - Identifier 'pathToChat' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:107:26 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:109:21 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:110:18 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
ERROR: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:111:16 - This assertion is unnecessary since it does not change the type of the expression.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:115:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:115:9 - Identifier 'batch' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:117:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:117:9 - Identifier 'ref1' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:118:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/Functions.ts:118:9 - Identifier 'ref2' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:50:5 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:69:9 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:69:13 - Identifier 'requestWrapper' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:146:13 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:146:17 - Identifier 'inJsonFormat' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:169:18 - == should be ===
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:172:22 - == should be ===
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:172:54 - == should be ===
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:200:48 - == should be ===
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:208:17 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:208:21 - Identifier 'inJsonFormat' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:241:46 - == should be ===
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:249:17 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:249:21 - Identifier 'inJsonFormat' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:266:13 - Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
WARNING: D:/func/functions/src/index.ts:266:17 - Identifier 'inJson' is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'var'.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-12T15_38_20_403Z-debug.log
error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

Any Suggestions will be a great help.

Comment: Looks like you have a lot of lint errors and warnings to resolve.  Read them carefully.

Comment: _Any Suggestions will be a great help._ The warnings and errors tell you exactly what the problem is, how much more can we do?

Comment: And I solved my problem by removing the no_unnecessary_assertion permission from tslint.json file. Now my functions are compiling and I have uploaded them successfully.